# jQuery is undefined exception in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

In IE11 I get this exception

> 'jQuery' is undefined

I do not get this error in any other browser. The code that is causing the problem is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
```

Any one know why is that and what might be causing the problem?

Comment: have you include jquery file

Comment: It may also be helpful to specify the version of jQuery that you're using

Comment: If the error is only happening in IE11 then it might be a matter of the order in which the scripts are loaded. Is the jquery file the first js file you're loading?

Comment: @Riturajratan OP said that he is not getting the error in other browsers!

Comment: Hey thanks for reply it only happens with IE 11. I use richfaces version 3.X Jquery version is 1.4.2.

Comment: jQuery 1.4.2 is pretty much stoneage...

Comment: I know. But the point that i do not get why it is working well with all browsers even the old versions of IE. But not IE11??

Comment: It might be a bug in old jQuery; use a more current version and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Problem solved. I was missing the a:loadscript tag for the jquery.js  in richfaces.

Comment: but still it worked in other browsers?  Isn't that a bit odd?

Comment: Yes i agree with you. It did work with other browsers so good and i didnt need to include <a:loadscript tag for the Jquery.js it was loading automatically but in IE11 it didnot work properly. And actually including the a:loadscript tag caused other problems so i had to remove it and find other solution. :\ dont know actually. its a bit weird.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE11 JQuery error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178845/ie11-jquery-error)

Comment: @NinoFiliu this is asked 5 years, 4 months ago

Answer (score 6):

In IE11, depending on your security settings, access to external CDNs may be blocked.

Thus, you will have to add 2 JQuery URLs, one for (every other browser) and one locally.

```
// First try loading jQuery from Google's CDN
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

// Fall back to a local copy of jQuery if the CDN fails
<script>
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>
```

Reference:
https://bugsnag.com/blog/jquery-is-not-defined-cause-solution

Comment: are these security settings client specific? Or can configuration server side solve the issues?

Comment: They are client-side specific.

Comment: At this point you might be better off just including jQuery in your build process.

Answer (score 6):

I came across the same issue in Internet Explorer 11. It occurs due to compatibility mode is auto set to Internet Explorer 7. Image is attached.

I use jQuery 2.2 in my project. It seems to be that only IE9 and upwards support for this version.

[image: Internet Explorer Compatibility List]

To force the compatibility mode use below meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" >
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if 'jquery' package is installed or not.
Then, you have to check the jquery version in the .js file you're referencing to, to be the same as your jquery files in 'Scripts'.