# IE11 JQuery error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have code that works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE 11. I'm getting next error messages:

```
   1) SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined
    For this line of code:
    $.extend({ 
      )} 

   2)SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined
         // Browser globals
            factory( jQuery );

   3)SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
        .catch( function( error ) {
            jQuery.readyException( error );
        } );
```

Here is my header tag with all includes:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/JQuery_alert.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/jquery-ui.structure.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/jquery-ui.theme.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

I found that if I open my dev tools in IE and then in the upper right corner click on the Document mode and switch to Edge my code with all the includes above works fine. So my question is what is Edge? How I can make sure that someone else using IE will not have the problems running my page? Is there the way to fix that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this site running locally or did you deploy it somewhere to test? I've had issues with IE 11 and the default behavior of "display intranet sites in compatibility mode" checkbox

Comment: This is running on my test site, my code files and JQuery files are in the same directory.  How and where I have to check compatibility mode and how to set Edge?

Comment: If the site's in development you can append `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to the `<head>` element which will coerce IE to run in Edge mode instead of IE8.

Comment: In addition to compatibility mode, there is also quirks mode, which is even worse (it emulates IE5, and jQuery definitely will not work with it). To prevent Quirks Mode, make sure your HTML starts with a valid doctype. If you haven't done this already, the easiest way is to make this the first line of your HTML: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I unchecked  compatibility view and tried to include the meta tag for IE edge but still getting an error for every line of JQUery code. I'm not sure what else can cause this error...

Comment: Change the includes to use JQuery 1.x, and see if some things start working.  This would be a valuable clue, and help prove the theory here.  Also open up fiddler and make sure all the files are found, and not having an error loading.

Comment: @Thriggle I have switched to Edge in Developer tools and everything works fine! How I can make sure that this will work for all users?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Compatibility View**

When Internet Explorer runs in compatibility view, it emulates older versions such as IE8 which is incompatible with the latest version of jQuery (only the 1.x versions of jQuery are compatible with older versions of IE).

**Checking if Compatibility View is the Problem**

When you hit F12 in Internet Explorer, it should bring up the Developer Tools. Near the top right of the toolbar, you should find a drop down that lets you switch between Edge, 10, 9, 8, 7, and 5. Switching it will cause the page to refresh using the new document mode. If you switch to Edge and you still get the jQuery errors, then you can rule out compatibility view as the problem.

**Making sure the page won't be displayed in Compatibility View**

Check the documentation here regarding specifying document modes for Internet Explorer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj676915.aspx

You can also try to force IE11 to display in Edge mode by inserting a `<meta>` tag into the Header of your HTML (it should be the first tag within the Header) like so:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
...
```

This instructs Internet Explorer to explicitly use that document mode.

Comment: the web.config equivalent: 
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  <system.webServer>

Answer (score 0):

You can also experience issues if your jquery references are stored in a .jspf file that is referenced as an include. IBM Websphere will cache the jspf's in a temp folder on the server and they will not be replaced even with a ear/war deploy. It is necessary to remove those files from the temp folder.