# Rails 5 + jQuery: $ is not defined in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer

I am using the jquery 3 gem in my Rails 5 app and everything runs smoothly except for Internet Explorer (any version, including 11).  At the bottom of my homepage I have a script tag:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { ... })
</script>
```

and this throws an error `'$' is not defined`, but only on Internet Explorer.  The strange thing is that after the page loads, if I type `$("h1")` into the console, the function successfully fires.

Any idea what to do here?

Comment: What is the version of IE you are using?

Comment: 11, my apologies, I'll update the question

Comment: Try the answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178845/ie11-jquery-error

Comment: No luck. didn't make a difference